# Are we rewarded for dhikr in the mind only without uttering a single word?

Tags: dua, dhikr

Are we rewarded for dhikr in the mind of the type of saying 1000 times estagfirullah, la ilahe ilallah,  Alhamdulilah, ja mukal libel kulubi thebit kalbi ala dinik in the mind only without uttering a single sound or word? In other word you say them only in the mind without moving the lips.

And Does Allah accept and reward an invocation or supplication of the type: Allah please give me good understanding of quran and sunnah, Allah please give me strong iman, Allah please give me good health and solve my problems, if it is done in the mind only without moving the lips, without uttering any word or sound?

Comment: I was thinking about this today, when came here saw this I was what a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

It is not thought that is judged, only what is expressed and done. In other words, your actions are what counts and that includes expression of thoughts whether through speech, writing, or other media. For example you cannot just think about the shahada, you have to express the words audibly to witnesses.  The same applies for performing dhikr.  As with salah, it is more sebab to perform dhikr in a group (two or more) where you can hear and witness each other's dhikr.  The external manifestation of your thought and intention is the confirmation of it to yourself and to other witnesses.  If you are performing salah by yourself you are only getting 1/27 of the benefit than what you get by performing in a group according to sahih hadith.  When you are performing salah by youself, then you must recite the words of the salah audibly to yourself, doesn't have to be loud, just enough for you to hear them.

To better understand this it is helpful to get into some ontology and look at the 10 spiritual portals of the heart: the mouth, the nose, the ears, the eyes, the face, the head, the neck, the hands, the feet, and the gender organs.  These portals to the heart must be purified through wudu (Quran 5:6) and/or ghusl before one can perform the salah, or touch the muzhaf (Quran 56:79).

In order to complete a valid act of worship there needs to be an output from a suitable portal from oneself or others, matched with an input from a portal. If you are performing dhikr by yourself, you ouput the dhikr through your mouth by speech, so that you can audibly input through your ears, completing the loop, confirming and strengthening the spiritual heart and getting closer to Allah.

If the worshipper is deaf and/or speech impaired and is alone by his/her self, then with Allah's help he/she needs to find a way to use the other suitable portals to perform the dhikr.  Its easier and more sebab to just participate in group dhikr so that the speech output is done by others, and you just input. If you must do the dhikr alone, where there is a will, there is a way.

The late physicist Stephen Hawking lost 90 % of his neural muscular motor control, competely paralyzed from Lou Gehrigs disease, but that did not prevent him from his great accomplishments in physics.  Worshiping Allah swt is even more important.  That is why Allah swt created mankind and the jin, to worship Allah swt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

> Abu Hurairah (My Allah be pleased with him) reported:
> The messenger of Allah (PBUH) said, "Allah the Exalted says: 'I am as my slave expects me to be, and I am with him when he remembers Me. If he remembers Me inwardly, I will remember him inwardly, and if he remembers Me in an assembly, I will remember him in a better assembly (i.e., in the assembly of angels)."
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim]

And there is no wrong thing about your innovative supplication but it's better to use the supplications mentioned in Quran and Sunnah.

[Source to the Hadith](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1435)

Comment: Please mark your quotes as such (see my edit for future posts). Note that there are certainly better evidences.

Answer (score -1):

Every moment spent in the remembrance of our Lord is rewarded. You don't have to say it out loud to get reward.

There is the Hadith that tells Muslims to stop oppression when they see it. They should stop it with force if they can. If they can't use force, they should stop it with their words. If they can't say something against it out loud, then know it in their hearts that it is wrong.

Hadith:

> On the authority of Abu Sa`eed al-Khudree (may Allah be pleased with 
>   him) who said:
>
> I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say, “Whosoever of you sees an evil, 
>   let him change it with his hand; and if he is not able to do so, then [let him change it] with his tongue; and if he is not able to do so, then with his heart — and that is the weakest of faith.” [Muslim]

If knowing that a sin is wrong in your heart is acceptable, why not dhikr and supplication?

[Reference](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/16/28)

Comment: Only the first sentence addresses the topic of the question.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.